# I went to my gym. Is this correct?

Tags: relative-clauses, prepositions

Use of 'my' with School or college is correct. Is it good to use with gym, coaching center.

Comment: Perfectly fine.  In most cases people would say "I went to *the* gym", but that could be confusing if you went to a different gym from what the hearer would likely assume.  (In which case "my gym" is more appropriate.)

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: yes. It can be used if you are merely a participant at the gym or sports center, or if you have a gym of your own at your personal residence.

If you are rich and famous, you may even have a gym named after you, (at a school or university, for example,) in which case you can still claim it as 'my' gym.